# How to use node modules and require with Express 4 router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url-routing, node-modules

I've used an express 4 generator for node project initiation. It uses a router and I have the following:

```
// ./routes/index.js

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Now, I want to add the following route within it.

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) { return next(err) }
        if (!user) {
            req.flash('error', info.message);
            return res.redirect('/login')
        }
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            return res.redirect('/');
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

It needs to have access to `app` and `passport` I think. Can you please tell me how can the routing file `index.js` access `passport` and what should I `module.export` from this file `index.js` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`app.post` can be replaced with the `router.post` as you have already got router module in this script. The change you will have to do is to require the `passport` module in this page and use it.

could be like

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) { return next(err) }
        if (!user) {
            req.flash('error', info.message);
            return res.redirect('/login')
        }
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            return res.redirect('/');
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});

module.exports = router;
```